# Concatenate \u sign with a string in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, nsstring, string-concatenation

I can't figure out how to concatenate Unicode sign `\u` with string like `f1bc` properly to get `\uf1bc`. Any ideas how to do it?

Reason: The API I currently use sends me Unicode signs without `\u`...
Response looks like this (one from `NSDictionary` keys):

```
"icon" : "f1bc",
```

Comment: Do you want to get a string with the characters "\uf1bc" or the character with the unicode f1bc? (Which is inside the private area of unicode!)

Comment: character to display in uilabel. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: Look to my answer. But I'm not sure, whether it is avaiblabe. Maybe it is utf8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accoring to your comment, you cannot do that with concatenating \u and the hex code. This is interpreted at compile time.

You have to get the unicode value first and then transform it into the character:

```
NSString* unicodeString = …; // @"f1bc"
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:unicodeString];
unsigned unicode;
[scanner scanHexInt:&unicode];
NSString *stringWithUnicodeChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", (unichar)unicode];
```

Typped in Safari.

Comment: I'd use `unichar` type and check the return value of `scanHexInt:`

Comment: Of course, sorry. But it is only to show the approach.

Comment: works like a charm! Thanks. FYI second approach gives warning:Incompatible pointer types sending 'unichar *' (aka 'unsigned short *') to parameter of type 'unsigned int *'

Comment: Yes, there is no `-scanHexUnicode:`. You can get rid of it, if you use int (as I did before the edit) and then assign it to `unichar`. I'm on the way to the german disaster against france. I will edit it later.